# Website works with safari but not in Google Chrome or Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, safari

www.thebusslab.com

If you go to this URL in your Chrome or Firefox browser the footer and bottom half of the home page doesn't load? If you open the site in a Safari browser it loads properly. I'm not sure why this happens at all and any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML doesn't validate:

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thebusslab.com&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Fix these and you'll be fine.

Comment: Just a note: just because HTML doesn't validate doesn't necessarily mean it won't work. Most browsers are very, very forgiving. And I'd be willing to bet most websites you go to won't actually validate.

Comment: True. But validating the number of opening tags matches the number of closing tags is a quick, easy place to find any layout issues. In this case there was an extra closing </div>

Answer (score 1):

Most likely an issue with your HTML.

You have a couple of stray tags.

Lines: 24, 137/138, 156

Answer (score 0):

Remove `overflow: hidden` from the second `.grid-wrap` section.
That makes the bottom half visible in Chrome.

Comment: I made the change in the CSS file and it still doesn't fix the issue? Am i missing something simple?